# Android Kotlin app from play store crashes: Type kotlin.Pair not present. java.lang.TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, runtimeexception

I just released a new app on the Play Store. The app was working fine on my phone before submission but when I download the app from play store, it crashed on launch. I have tried deleting the app from the phone and re-installing and that continues to crash on launch.

When I have the phone connected to Android Studio, I see this logged when the crash occurs.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.MyApplication: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type kotlin.Pair not present
```

Why would kotlin.Pair not be available on the play store version of the app?? I haven't submitted any apps to play store since around 2018 so I am a bit rusty but I kind of remember having a similar experience before and I think it had something to do with Proguard but I am not sure. How can I fix this and how can I test the app beforehand on how it's going to behave when it's downloaded from Playstore?

Full:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2021-08-09 00:09:03.067 13733-13733/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bundleid.EXAMPLE, PID: 13733
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.MyApplication: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type kotlin.Pair not present
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7700)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
     Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type kotlin.Pair not present
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:69)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getOwnerType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:54)
        at p4.a.a(Unknown Source:35)
        at p4.a$a.<init>(Unknown Source:3)
        at p4.a.a(Unknown Source:63)
        at t4.a.<init>(:1)
        at v4.t3.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.MyApplication.onCreate(:23)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6754)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7700) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.Pair
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getOwnerType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:54) 
        at p4.a.a(Unknown Source:35) 
        at p4.a$a.<init>(Unknown Source:3) 
        at p4.a.a(Unknown Source:63) 
        at t4.a.<init>(:1) 
        at v4.t3.<init>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.MyApplication.onCreate(:23) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6754) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7700) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.Pair
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67) 
        at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getOwnerType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:54) 
        at p4.a.a(Unknown Source:35) 
        at p4.a$a.<init>(Unknown Source:3) 
        at p4.a.a(Unknown Source:63) 
        at t4.a.<init>(:1) 
        at v4.t3.<init>(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.MyApplication.onCreate(:23) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6754) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7700) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
```

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bundleid.EXAMPLE"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.4.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0")
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.github.blipinsk:ViewPropertyObjectAnimator:1.5.0'
    implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
}
```

My `proguard-rules.pro` file is empty.

**EDIT:**

I was able to at least reproduce the same issue using the release build of the app using:

```
brew install bundletool
cd /location/to/your/release/folder
bundletool build-apks --bundle=app-release.aab --output=./app.apks
ls
bundletool install-apks --apks=app.apks --adb=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Now I just need to figure out how to fix the crash.

**EDIT 2:**

If I set `minifyEnabled` to false in build.gradle, then it doesn't crash. So it definitely has to do with Proguard. How can I fix it?

**EDIT 3:**

I was able to resolve this by putting this in the `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }

-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep interface kotlin.** { *; }

-keep class com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.** { *; }
-keep interface com.bundleid.EXAMPLE.** { *; }
```

This works. But if someone thinks these rules might be incorrect or too broad, please let me know.

Comment: You can debug your any release version from IDE also , select release as "Active Build Variant" from `Build | Select Build Variant`  Menu of Android Studio , then add `"android:debuggable="true"`  to your Manifest inside the `<application>`  tag . Run app from IDE and debug now

Comment: You could modify the `proguard-rules.pro`.

Comment: @dan1st I am aware. I want to know what should I add there? I am not sure why Kotlin's basic type `Pair` isn't available.

Comment: It kind of looks like you're keeping everything so there's no point in using minification at that point. Though I can't explain why a class you're using like Pair would have been stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this after increasing an existing app's `targetSdkVersion` from 29 to 30. Adding just this to `proguard-rules.pro` seems to fix it for me:

```
-keep class kotlin.Pair
```